# Does the cv::Mat parentheses operator copy or reference an area of interest?

Tags: opencv, mat

This [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4272fce43d7405603fbb5e5f52580e57&gsc.tab=0) defines a parentheses operator on `cv::Mat` that takes in a rectangular area of interest of type `cv::Rect` as a parameter:

`Mat cv::Mat::operator() (const Rect & roi) const`

But the documentation doesn't explain the semantics of the operator. Does it copy the area of interest? Or does it reference it in the new Mat that is created?

If I change the original Mat, will the new one change too?

*My guess is that it copies, since the roi is not in most cases a contiguous block of memory. But nowhere does the documentation say that explicitly, so I just want to make sure it's not pulling some special memory trick that ends up coupling the two Mats.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference, unless you explicitly copy the data.

---

You can see this using a small example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rect r(0,0,2,2);
    Mat1b mat(3,3, uchar(0));
    cout << mat << endl;

    // mat
    // 0 0 0
    // 0 0 0
    // 0 0 0

    Mat1b submat_reference1(mat(r));
    submat_reference1(0,0) = 1;
    cout << mat << endl;
    cout << submat_reference1 << endl;

    // mat 
    // 1 0 0
    // 0 0 0
    // 0 0 0

    // submat_reference1
    // 1 0
    // 0 0

    Mat1b submat_reference2 = mat(r);
    submat_reference2(0, 0) = 2;
    cout << mat << endl;
    cout << submat_reference1 << endl;
    cout << submat_reference2<< endl;
    // mat
    // 2 0 0
    // 0 0 0
    // 0 0 0

    // submat_reference1 = submat_reference2
    // 2 0
    // 0 0


    Mat1b submat_deepcopy = mat(r).clone();
    submat_deepcopy(0,0) = 3;
    cout << mat << endl;
    cout << submat_reference1 << endl;
    cout << submat_reference2 << endl;
    cout << submat_deepcopy << endl;

    // mat      
    // 2 0 0
    // 0 0 0
    // 0 0 0

    // submat_reference1 = submat_reference2
    // 2 0
    // 0 0

    // submat_deepcopy 
    // 3 0 
    // 0 0

    return 0;
}
```